# Passing file name to function

Tags: c, file-handling

I have to fill two arrays that represent the coordinates of points and then to store them into a file.

Here I didn't wrote all the code I just mentioned the necessary, I must respect the format of arguments of the function save_file, but here I faced a problem: how should I pass the argument file to function? Is fptr is the file name? And also how should I use the argument inside the function, because when I run the program, I get the following warning:

> incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _IO_FILE *')
> passing argument to parameter '__stream'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "biblio.h"

int main(void)
{
 float *xi;
 float *yi;
 FILE * fptr = NULL;
 fptr = fopen("xypoint.dat","w");
 save_file("xypoint.dat",xi,yi);
 fcose(fptr);
 return 0;

}

void save_file(char * myfilename, double * xinterp, double * yinterp)
{
  int n=4;
  while( n-- > 0 )
  {
    fprintf(myfilename,"%.3f  %.3f\n",*(xinterp++),*(yinterp++));
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not how you work with files in C.

Comment: `fptr` is not the file name.  Is a pointer to a `FILE` `struct`ure.

Comment: When in doubt, read the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing an array to a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625039/writing-an-array-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: Sorry, i'm a beginner, when i have to pass argument to save_file function, i tried to pass fptr, this gives me warning, then i tried to pass the file name, but there also another probleme inside the function how do i use fprintf to write into my file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
...
int main(void)
{
  float *xi;
  float *yi;
  // you need to initialize xi and yi, but I supposed
  // you omitted this for brevity
  save_file("xypoint.dat", xi, yi);
  return 0;
}

void save_file(char *myfilename, double *xinterp, double *yinterp)
{
  FILE *fptr = fopen(myfilename, "w");
  // no error checking for brevity

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  // use for here, it shows the intention clearly
  {
    fprintf(fptr, "%.3f  %.3f\n", xinterp[i], yinterp[i]);  // use [] here,
                                                            // it's more readable
  }

  fclose(fptr);
}
```

Be aware that the `incompatible pointer types ...` warnings are rather errors than warnings.

Comment: Yes, it works but when i passe the argument  "xypoint.dat to save_file, why it does work ? i didn't mentioned before the "xypoint.dat" ?, and another question in the while loop ? is there another way to check the while loop, because here i have put n=4, but in reality it is more, and i can't pass the number of pts as parameter, how to make loop the nomber of x,y couple times ?

Comment: @ElMehdiAKKOUCHE because the first argument of `save_file` is the pointer to the filename and `"xypoint.dat"` is a string literal which is a pointer to the filename. Why shouldn'tt work?

Comment: Add `printf("Opening file %s\n", myfilename);` as first line of `save_file` and see what happens. All this is covered in the chapter dealing with strings and in the chapter dealing with files in your beginner's C text book.

Comment: is there another way to iterate the right number of times, because here i cheated while declaring int n=4. i tried to put while(  ( fprintf(fptr, "%.3f  %.3f\n", xinterp[i], yinterp[i]) ) == 2), like when we deal with fscanf, but it does not work.

Comment: @ElMehdiAKKOUCHE I didn't understand the question in your last comment at all, but I think you should ask a new question, as this is not really related to your original question.

Comment: The question is, is there another way to write the right number of elements of the array without using the number n, because here i cheated, i can't pass parameter as number of elements of the arrays

Comment: @ElMehdiAKKOUCHE you need to ask another question. This is no more related to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide to open/close the file inside or outside the `save_file` function.

If you open the file **inside** the `save_file` function,
you pass the **file name**, which has type `char *`.

```c
int main(void)
{
  // ...
  save_file("xypoint.dat", xi, yi); // pass FILENAME to save_file
}

void save_file(char *myfilename, double *xinterp, double *yinterp)
{
  FILE *fptr = fopen(myfilename, "w"); // open file INSIDE save_file
  
  // write the file
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    // use `fptr`(the return value from fopen), not `myfilename`
    fprintf(fptr, "%.3f  %.3f\n", xinterp[i], yinterp[i]);
  }

  fclose(fptr); // close file INSIDE save_file
}
```

If you open the file **outside** the `save_file` function,
you pass the **opened file structure pointer**, which has type `FILE *`.

```c
int main(void)
{
  // ...
  FILE *fptr = fopen("xypoint.dat", "w"); // open file OUTSIDE save_file
  save_file(fptr, xi, yi); // pass FILE* to save_file
  fclose(fptr); // close file OUTSIDE save_file
}

void save_file(FILE *fptr, double *xinterp, double *yinterp)
{
  // no need to open file again
  
  // write the file
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    // use `fptr` directly
    fprintf(fptr, "%.3f  %.3f\n", xinterp[i], yinterp[i]);
  }

  // no need to close file here
}
```

Comment: but i have to respect the given function's declaration, its first argument must be of type char* not FILE*,i suppose that there is only one choise for me, the first one.

Comment: If you can not change the declaration in `biblio.h`, you are supposed to open the file inside the `save_file` function. In that case, yes, you have to use the first one.